# Writing a custom plugin for dita2html2 in DITA-OT1.8.5

Tags: html, dita, dita-ot

I tried a custom plugin for dita2html2 in DITA-OT1.8.5.

Custom plugin Name {com.dita2html2.xhtml}

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  This file is part of the DITA Open Toolkit project.
  See the accompanying license.txt file for applicable licenses.
-->
<plugin id="com.dita2html2.xhtml">
  <!-- extensions -->
  <require plugin="net.sourceforge.dita4publishers.common.mapdriven"/> 
  <require plugin="net.sourceforge.dita4publishers.common.xslt"/> 

  <template file="build_xhtml-dita2html2_template.xml"/>

  <template file="xsl/map2html2_template.xsl"/>

  <feature extension="dita.conductor.transtype.check" value="xhtml-dita2html2" type="txt"/>
  <feature extension="dita.conductor.target.relative" file="build.xml"/>
  <!-- change value to match your custom transtype -->
</plugin>
```

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="com.dita2html2.xhtml">
  <import file="build_xhtml-dita2html2.xml"/>
</project>
```

build_xhtml-dita2html2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><project name="xhtml-dita2html2" default="dita2xhtml-dita2html2">

    <!-- Controls debugging within the XSLTs. Set to "true" to turn on debugging: -->
    <property name="debug" value="false"></property>

    <target name="dita2xhtml-dita2html2" unless="noMap" depends="d4p.map-driven-build-init,build-init,preprocess,html3">
  </target>

  <target name="html3" unless="noMap" depends="dita.map.html3"></target>


  <target name="dita.map.html3.init" description="Init properties for HTML2">

    <property name="d4p.is.map.driven" value="true"></property>

    <condition property="topics.output.dir" value="topics">
        <not>
            <isset property="topics.output.dir"></isset>
      </not>
    </condition>

    <!-- The name of the directory, within the output package, to contain all images: -->

    <condition property="images.output.dir" value="images">
        <not>
          <isset property="images.output.dir"></isset>
        </not>
    </condition>

    <property name="html2.temp.dir" value="${dita.temp.dir}${file.separator}html2_temp"></property>

    <!-- Defines the @class value to use for topic elements generated for topicheads. -->
    <condition property="title.only.topic.class.spec" value="- topic/topic ">
        <not>
          <isset property="title.only.topic.class.spec"></isset>
        </not>
    </condition>

    <!-- Defines the @class value to use for topic title elements generated for topicheads. -->
    <condition property="title.only.topic.title.class.spec" value="- topic/title ">
        <not>
          <isset property="title.only.topic.title.class.spec"></isset>
        </not>
    </condition>

    <basename property="dita.map.toc.root" file="${dita.input.filename}" suffix=".ditamap"></basename>
    <condition property="args.html2.toc" value="${dita.map.toc.root}">
      <not>
        <isset property="args.html2.toc"></isset>
      </not>
    </condition>
    <condition property="out.ext" value=".html">
      <not>
        <isset property="out.ext"></isset>
      </not>
    </condition>
    <condition property="noPlugin">
      <equals arg1="${dita.html2.plugin}" arg2="no"></equals>
    </condition>
    <condition property="css.output.dir" value="css">
      <not>
        <isset property="args.css.output.dir"></isset>
      </not>
    </condition>
    <condition property="css.output.dir" value="${args.css.output.dir}">
      <isset property="args.css.output.dir"></isset>
    </condition>

    <condition property="html2.doDynTocFileCopy">
        <or>
            <not>
              <isset property="html2.generate.dynamic.toc"></isset><!-- Default is true for dyntoc. -->
            </not>
        <equals arg1="${html2.generate.dynamic.toc}" arg2="true"></equals>
        <equals arg1="${html2.generate.dynamic.toc}" arg2="yes"></equals>
        <equals arg1="${html2.generate.dynamic.toc}" arg2="1"></equals>
        </or>
   </condition>

    <condition property="html2.do.copy.graphics" value="true">
        <not>
            <isset property="html2.do.copy.graphics"></isset>
      </not>
    </condition>


    <echo message="+++ html2-specific properties:"></echo>
    <echoproperties format="text" regex="^(html2|css|out\.)" taskname="echo"></echoproperties>
  </target>

  <target name="dita.map.html3" depends="dita.map.html3.init, html2-copy-css, html2-copy-dyntoc-javascript" description="Generate all ePub components from input map and topics">

    <mkdir dir="${html2.temp.dir}"></mkdir>
    <makeurl file="${output.dir}" property="html2.xslt.outdir"></makeurl>
    <makeurl file="${dita.temp.dir}" property="html2.xslt.tempdir"></makeurl>

    <property name="map2html2.style" location="${dita.plugin.net.sourceforge.dita4publishers.html2.dir}/xsl/map2html2.xsl"></property>
    <property name="args.xhtml.toc" value="index"></property>

    <xslt processor="trax" basedir="${dita.temp.dir}" destdir="${output.dir}" includesfile="${dita.temp.dir}${file.separator}user.input.file.list" classpathref="dost.class.path" style="${map2html2.style}" filenameparameter="inputFileNameParam">
        <param name="cssOutputDir" expression="${css.output.dir}"></param>
      <param name="debug" expression="${debug}"></param>
        <param name="fileOrganizationStrategy" expression="${html2.file.organization.strategy}" if="html2.file.organization.strategy"></param>
      <param name="generateDynamicToc" expression="${html2.generate.dynamic.toc}" if="html2.generate.dynamic.toc"></param>
      <param name="generateFrameset" expression="${html2.generate.frameset}" if="html2.generate.frameset"></param>
      <param name="generateStaticToc" expression="${html2.generate.static.toc}" if="html2.generate.static.toc"></param>
        <param name="generateIndex" expression="${html2.generate.index}" if="html2.generate.index"></param>
        <param name="imagesOutputDir" expression="${images.output.dir}"></param>        
        <param name="outdir" expression="${html2.xslt.outdir}"></param>
        <!-- NOTE: Case of OUTEXT matches parameter used in base HTML transform type -->
        <param name="OUTEXT" expression="${out.ext}"></param><!-- Extension to use for result files, e.g., ".html" -->
        <param name="tempdir" expression="${html2.xslt.tempdir}"></param>
        <param name="rawPlatformString" expression="${os.name}"></param>
        <param name="titleOnlyTopicClassSpec" expression="${title.only.topic.class.spec}"></param>
        <param name="titleOnlyTopicTitleClassSpec" expression="${title.only.topic.title.class.spec}"></param>
        <param name="topicsOutputDir" expression="${topics.output.dir}"></param>

        <!-- Parameters from dita2xhtml and similar transtypes: -->   
      <param name="WORKDIR" expression="${workdir}" if="workdir"></param>
      <param name="CSS" expression="${args.css.file}" if="args.css.file"></param>
      <param name="CSSPATH" expression="${user.csspath}" if="user.csspath"></param>
      <param name="DRAFT" expression="${args.draft}" if="args.draft"></param>
      <param name="ARTLBL" expression="${args.artlbl}" if="args.artlbl"></param>
      <param name="GENERATE-TASK-LABELS" expression="${args.gen.task.lbl}" if="args.gen.task.lbl"></param>
      <param name="PRESERVE-DITA-CLASS" expression="${args.xhtml.classattr}" if="args.xhtml.classattr"></param>
      <param name="NOPARENTLINK" expression="${args.hide.parent.link}" if="args.hide.parent.link"></param>
      <param name="BREADCRUMBS" expression="${args.breadcrumbs}" if="args.breadcrumbs"></param>
      <param name="INDEXSHOW" expression="${args.indexshow}" if="args.indexshow"></param>
        <param name="OUTPUTDIR" expression="${output.dir}"></param>
        <param name="FILEDIR" expression="."></param>
      <mapper type="glob" from="${user.input.file}" to="${args.xhtml.toc}${out.ext}"></mapper>
    </xslt>

    <condition property="skip.copy.graphics" value="${local.skip.copy.graphics}">
        <isset property="local.skip.copy.graphics"></isset>
    </condition>

    <antcall target="html2.copy.graphics">
        <param name="do.copy.graphics" value="${local.skip.copy.graphics}"></param>
    </antcall>
  </target>

  <target name="html2.copy.graphics" unless="skip.copy.graphics" description="Copies graphics from input to the output directory based on the graphic map generated during html2 generation">
    <ant antfile="${output.dir}/copy-graphics.xml">
    </ant>
    </target>

  <target name="html2-copy-dyntoc-javascript" description="Copy JavaScript files" depends="dita.map.html3.init" if="html2.doDynTocFileCopy">
    <copy todir="${output.dir}">
      <fileset dir="${dita.plugin.com.dita2html2.xhtml.dir}/dynamic-toc-support">
            <include name="**/*"></include>
        </fileset>
    </copy>

    </target>

  <target name="html2-copy-css" description="Copy CSS files" depends="dita.map.html3.init">    
    <condition property="user.copycss.yes">
      <isset property="args.css.present"></isset>
    </condition>
    <property name="user.csspath.real" value="${output.dir}${file.separator}${css.output.dir}"></property>
    <mkdir dir="${user.csspath.real}"></mkdir>    
    <!-- Always copy system default css files -->
    <copy todir="${user.csspath.real}">
      <fileset dir="${dita.resource.dir}" includes="*.css"></fileset>
    </copy>    
    <copy todir="${user.csspath.real}">
      <fileset dir="${dita.plugin.com.dita2html2.xhtml.dir}/css">
            <include name="**/*"></include>
      </fileset>        
    </copy>
    <!-- Copy user specify css file when required -->
    <antcall target="html2-copy-css-user"></antcall>
  </target>

  <target name="html2-copy-css-user" if="user.copycss.yes">
    <copy file="${args.css.real}" todir="${user.csspath.real}"></copy>
  </target>
</project>
```

While running in oXygen Editor {Version: 18} I come across errors as below

```
dita.map.html3:
[mkdir]Createddir:E:\task\temp\xhtml-dita2html2\oxygen_dita_temp\html2_temp
[xslt]TransformingintoE:\task\out\xhtml-dita2html2
[xslt]ProcessingE:\task\temp\xhtml-dita2html2\oxygen_dita_temp\Test.ditamaptoE:\task\out\xhtml-dita2html2\index.html
[xslt]LoadingstylesheetC:\DITA-OT\DITA-OT1.8.5-XHTML\plugins\com.dita2html2.xhtml\xsl\map2html2.xsl
[xslt]Failedtoprocessnull
```

Would there be a way to pass the above errors. Can anyone guide me. I'm new to dita2html2 conversion and DITA too.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the ANT publishing using the "-verbose" flag (or if you are running the "dita" command use the "-d" flag) you should receive in the console more details about the failure. Also if you place your entire plugin somewhere and add a link to it, maybe me or somebody else can test the plugin and give you more hints.